# Entity Reference get nodes based on tags

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

Let me try my best to make myself understood.

I have a node type Exhibition where I want to display related nodes of type Article, and these related nodes are tagged with taxonomy tags. On the Exhibition node I want a field where I can write one or more words, and related Articles tagged with these words should be displayed.

I want to use the Entity Reference module since this is already in use elsewhere, and I want to limit the number of modules in use. (I know of the Similar By Terms module).

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done with Entity Reference out of the box, your only option is to install another module or write some custom code (you would need to create a custom widget that searched additional fields on the entity if you went down the custom code route).

One possibility, which seems to be in keeping with your approach, is the [Entity Reference View Widget](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) module.  This module allows you to search on any field.  There is a little bit of additional setup since you have to create a view containing your Article nodes, but it means that you can specify your taxonomy as a field that can be filtered.

[image]

Comment: I would be careful with that module. It never became really stable and is an architectural dead end. (I wrote it)

Comment: Ah, I haven't actually tried the module but saw it on a recent Lullabot post.  You know best though, being the module author and all!!

Comment: I guess Similar By Terms module is the easiest way to go then since another module is needed anyway. Thank you both for answering.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454507/creating-list-of-similar-nodes-in-drupal-7-views-3 - Works great.

Comment: @BojanZivanovic Best comment I've seen in a while. Still have the same opinion?

Comment: The 2.x version is very stable, since it uses a dialog instead of embedding the view.