# Views to display events with single date events and events with date range

Tags: 7, datetime, views

I have a views view that displays a list of events. These events have a start-date and an end-date. I have two exposed filters, one for the start-date and one for the end-date, so that users can select a date range to view events. The page can be seen here:

[KODE Calendar page](http://kodebergen.no/en/calendar)

The filters check that start-date <= selected start-date and that end-date is >= selected end-date. This works if the event spans several days and start- and end-date falls outside the selected dates.

The question is, how can I include events that have start-date and end-date on the same day?

I tried to have another set of filters and use the and/or functionality, but alas, I was not able to reuse the exposed filter.

[image: My filter criteria]

Comment: I answered similar question here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73119/related-node-views-some-with-date-field/73123

If this answer is insufficient, please clarify why your situation is different, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: The difference now is that the filters are exposed, and that I am not able to reuse the exposed filters so that I can solve it like the similar question. A solution could be to reuse said filters, but I can not find any way to do this.

Comment: In condition like `published AND language AND ( content_without_end_date OR (content_with_end_date AND end_date_ok ) )` why would you ever need to use end date twice? It appears only once. Checking for it's very existence does not need to be exposed, right?

Comment: Because then I could also include events where start-date >= selected start-date, and end-date is <= selected end-date. I will try to find out how I can rewrite my question, it probably wasn't to obvious.

Comment: _The question is, how can I include events that have start-date and end-date on the same day?_ Well, I can't see why this should malfunction with filters like `start-date <= selected start-date and end-date is >= selected end-date`

You have no results if start-date == end-date?

Comment: Yes. In combination with showing events that has an end-date > start-date. The way it works now is that I can either show single date events or events that span over several days. Not both. Not without reusing the exposed filters, and using groups to check for dates the way described above. At least not in any way I can see.

Comment: Wait, what? If you have two filters: `show only events started later than 3 days ago` and `show only events that will end no sooner than 4 days from now`, you can't get both events that _starts today and ends today_ and _events started yesterday, will end tomorrow_ ?

Comment: That is right. Either I can have events shown that has a 'start-date > selected start-date' **and** 'end-date < selected end-date' **or** events that has a 'start-date < selected start-date' **and** 'end-date > selected end-date'. So when I select a start-date '2013-05-01' and end-date '2013-05-31', events starting after '2013-05-01' or ending before '2013-05-31' is not displayed.

Comment: I give up, I can't understand what are you trying to achieve. Let's mark node's dates as (), and user's selection {}. From last comment it looks like you want to get events either outside or inside selected range, but not crossing it, like {()} or ({}) but not ({)}. And that's not what you seems to want from question's body, when you indicate you only want ({}) but it fails when all dates are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was completely unable to make myself understood when asking the question, I thought maybe the solution could clear things up. In the views view I filter  event dates like specified in the question. I then used the `hook_views_query_alter` to add an or group condition like so:

```
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter (&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name != 'events') { return; }

  global $language;
  $lang = $language->language;

  $start_date = isset ($_GET['field_from_date_value']['value']['date']) ? $_GET['field_from_date_value']['value']['date'] : date('Y-m-d');
  $end_date   = isset ($_GET['field_from_date_value2']['value']['date']) ? $_GET['field_from_date_value2']['value']['date'] : date('Y-m-d');

  $query->group_operator = 'OR';

  $status_condition = array (
    'field' => 'node.status',
    'value' => 1,
    'operator' => '='
  );

  $node_type_condition = array (
    'field' => 'node.type',
    'value' => array ('event'),
    'operator' => 'in'
  );

  $language_condition = array (
    'field' => 'node.language',
    'value' => array ($lang),
    'operator' => 'in'
  );

  $date_condition_value = array (
    'field' => "DATE_FORMAT(field_data_field_from_date.field_from_date_value, '%Y-%m-%d') >= :field_data_field_from_date_field_from_date_value",
    'value' => array (':field_data_field_from_date_field_from_date_value' => $start_date),
    'operator' => 'formula'
  );

  $date_condition_value2 = array (
    'field' => "DATE_FORMAT(field_data_field_from_date.field_from_date_value2, '%Y-%m-%d') <= :field_data_field_from_date_field_from_date_value2",
    'value' => array (':field_data_field_from_date_field_from_date_value2' => $end_date),
    'operator' => 'formula'
  );

  $condition_type = 'AND';

  $query->where[10]['conditions'] = array (
    $status_condition,
    $node_type_condition,
    $language_condition,
    $date_condition_value,
    $date_condition_value2
  );

  $query->where[10]['type'] = $condition_type;

}
```